# How can I make a PATCH request (with SSL) in Java?

Tags: java, rest, https

I need my Java application to make a PATCH request to a web server using SSL.

I have tried the following:

```
public String patchForm(FormDataMultiPart f, Map<String,String> headers) {
        Entity<FormDataMultiPart> entity = Entity.entity(f, f.getMediaType());
        webTarget.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
        Builder request = webTarget.request();
        if (headers != null){
            for (String key : headers.keySet()){
                request = request.header(key, headers.get(key));
            }
        }
        Response result = request.method("PATCH", entity);
        return result.readEntity(String.class);
    }
```

Where `Entity` is `javax.ws.rs.client.Entity` and `webTarget` is a `javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget`.

However, when I make the request, the server interprets it as a POST request and gives me the wrong response.

What could be the cause of the problem? Is there any way to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, doing and undoing, adding _HttpMethod=PATCH to the query string and then removing it because it turned out not to be necessary, especially adding a missing break to a switch close which was causing the patchForm function to not be called at all (yes, that was a stupid oversight which cost me hours of work), and then fixing the errors which kept cropping up, I have finally arrived at something which works.

The code which finally worked was the following:

```
public String patchForm(FormDataMultiPart f, Map<String,String> headers) {
        Entity<FormDataMultiPart> entity = Entity.entity(f, f.getMediaType());
        webTarget.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        webTarget.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND, true);
        Builder request = webTarget.request();
        headers.put("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
        if (headers != null){
            for (String key : headers.keySet()){
                request = request.header(key, headers.get(key));
            }
        }
        Response result = request.patch(entity);
        return result.readEntity(String.class);
}
```

Note that the Builder class has a built-in `patch` method. I was using an old library which did not have it. And yet, the method workaround is still necessary because otherwise I get an exception since the PATCH method is non-standard.

Also note that, when submitting multipart forms, it is important to register the Multipart feature. I have read that it is possible to register it either on the client by overriding the `configureClient` method (when writing a custom client) or on the web target. Doing it on the web target suited my needs better, but you can do it in whatever way works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

For a Patch you need to set which url you are hitting to be secure.
For example

Your webTarget will have

```
webTarget.path("https://secureUrlWichWillForceSsl.com");
```

if it starts with http:// it will not be secure and no SSL.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not with SSL but with the patch method itself. For some reason the server interprets the request as POST rather than PATCH.